# Debugging IE issue with blueimp (jQuery file upload)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, blueimp

I am working with blueimp with user_dirs (session based upload directories).

When the uploads complete in FF, Chrome, Safari, etc I see the thumbnail appear.

In IE 9 after the upload completes I see "Error SyntaxError: Invalid character".  The IE Dev Panel shows no errors.  AND... if I refresh the thumbnail shows up and the upload has succeeded.

In IE 8 it's the same but I get "Error [object Error]" and if refresh I see the upload has succeeded, thumbnail is present and linked.

If I pull the received JSON using Chrome I see entries like this:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "name": "us (1).jpg",
        "size": 40294,
        "type": "image\/jpeg",
        "url": "http:\/\/upload.mysite.com\/uploads\/9cb5b4df96928f247b5bce2d4ed8a300\/us%20%281%29.jpg",
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/upload.mysite.com\/uploads\/9cb5b4df96928f247b5bce2d4ed8a300\/thumbnail\/us%20%281%29.jpg",
        "delete_url": "http:\/\/upload.mysite.com\/blueimp\/server\/php\/?file=us%20%281%29.jpg",
        "delete_type": "DELETE"
    }]
}
```

**What is my next step to debug this?  Is there a way to access the actual error in IE's dev panel?**

// 5.29 12:27 CST Update

When IE is used it was getting a 404 on /cors/result.html in main.js:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );
```

When updated to the correct path:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/blueimp/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );
```

I now get "Error Empty file upload result" but as per before a refresh shows the upload has succeeded...

Found another 404 file:  jquery.xdr-transport.js

Corrected path and now all is well.

// End Update

Comment: In IE you could try the F12 Network tab and Start Capturing to see the actual request/response, if you haven't already. Compare the headers for content type and length and the actual encoding of the data with those from Chrome and see if you can spot any obvious differences?

Comment: Oy!  Hard lesson to learn- I had somehow missed that IE 9 has a Network tab on dev panel.  Found 404s on IE only jquery.xdr-transport.js.

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer!  You get the fiddy pints.  Much obliged for the lesson.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IE you could try the F12 `Network` tab and `Start Capturing` to see the actual request/response, if you haven't already. Compare the headers for content type and length and the actual encoding of the data with those from Chrome and see if you can spot any obvious differences?

Comment: It's saying "You may award your bounty in 22 hours."  Will add to my calendar for tomorrow.  Again - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My way to solve this issue for IE 9 was to upload the folder 'cors' to the website. This folder contains the files postmessage.html and result.html.
After using the inspector in IE 9 it becomes clear that IE 9 uses that result.html to receive the upload response from the server via GET. Since I didn't include this folder in my server files, I got this problem, only in IE 9. After analysing the server error log and reader the 404 message in the net panel of the IE 9 inspector I got to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason you may see 404 responses when uploading is due to the request length set on the application receiving the posted file(s).